# Can someone explain why there is OH in the Standard Reduction Potentials Table

Tags: redox

$$\ce{SO4^2− + H2O(l) + 2e− <=>  SO3^2− + 2OH−}$$

This is the half-reaction that I am having trouble understand.

I have read online that OH- is used to cancel out the protons(H+) in basic conditions, so does that mean that this half reaction only happens in basic environments? Or can this happen in acidic environments with the equation I balanced myself:

$$\ce{HSO3-(aq) + H2O(l) <=> HSO4-(aq) + 2H+(aq) +2e-}$$

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: I mean, such a simple equation is much better to write using mhchem and \ce{} MathJax syntax.

Comment: I will fix it, but do you know why there is OH? and if this reaction can happen in acidic conditions?

Comment: You can find the reaction version  for  acidic solutions too, with different standard reduction potential.

Answer (score 2):

Most aqueous redox reactions take place only in acidic solutions or only in basic ones, because the predominant species are often very different between these environments. The reaction you pose, set up for basic solution, is part of the rule.

Even reactions that do not seem to depend on $\ce{H^+(aq)}$ or $\ce{OH^-(aq)}$ might require the proper pH to be realized. For instance, the reaction

$\ce{Zn^{2+} +2e^- <=> Zn^0}$

cannot be realized under standard state conditions except in acidic solution; neutralizing the acid results in the zinc precipitating as a hydroxide or oxide and making the solution basic leads to formation of anionic hydroxozincate or oxozincate complexes. On a [Pourbaix diagram](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zn-pourbaix-diagram.svg) this shows up as the horizontal boundary between zinc ions and zinc metal terminating at the pH where precipitation takes over.

[image]

[License](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:GNU_Free_Documentation_License,_version_1.2)

Answer (score 1):

The standard reduction potential gives the potential that you would find under standard conditions. The standard conditions depend on how you write the half reaction. As written, you would have to measure the standard reduction potential at a hydroxide activity of one (i.e. pH of about 14). If you choose a different pH, you would measure a different potential (and you could extrapolate to standard conditions).

Whether the reduction would also happen at neutral or acidic pH depends on the half reaction you are looking at. It [seems](https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-us/question/the-following-reactions-represent-the-reduction-of-io3-ion-into-i-ion-in-acidic-and/) both basic and acidic work (I did not take the time to find a reputable source, though).

It is always possible to add $\ce{H+}$ on both sides to switch to acidic conditions. However, if you do that, the standard reduction potential of the new net reaction will be different. Also, without doing the experiment or looking it up, you would not know whether the reaction proceeds under these new conditions or not.

For example:

$$ \ce{IO3−(aq) + 3H2O(l) + 6e− <=>  I−(aq) + 6OH−(aq)}$$

turns into

$$\ce{IO3−(aq) + 6H+(aq) + 6e− <=> I−(aq) + 3H2O(l)}$$